# You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file Javascript

Tags: javascript, webpack

I'am trying to init a class with the following syntax:

`const slider = new Slider()`

I get this mistake:

> You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file

My Webpack Configurations look like this:

```
                         module: {
                           rules: [
                             {
                               test: /\.html$/,
                               loader: 'html-loader',
                               options: {
                                       attrs: false,
                               },
                            },
                            {
                              test: /\.js$/,
                              exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                              use: {
                                  loader: 'babel-loader',
                                  options: {
                                    presets: ['@babel/preset-env'],
                                  },
                              },
                            },
                          ],
                        },
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please provide the full error, including stack trace if there is one.

Answer (score 0):

You probably missing a loader for css but there is no way to be sure without seeing the name of the file